# How can I sort android 10 app updates by time of release?

Tags: android-10

Android 10 app update notifications do not include the name of the app. Some apps are intentionally not updated. Is there a way to tell which app has a newly available update? Perhaps an OS feature or a 3rd-party utility is available.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to sort all apps by the date of the most recently available update and also display the date of release of the installed version. Thank you!

Comment: This should be unrelated to the Android version, but more about the store app (possibly Google Play Store).